# How to download a ZipArchive recieved from a soap request

Tags: php, soap, php-ziparchive

I  have recieved a Base64 encoded string with a ZipArchive holding an EXCEL file. I know for sure it is OK, as I have downloaded this file by just copy-pasting it into freeformater.com page. I have used PHP code but I get an empty zip file.

I have made a Soap Request to a server and I got as a response a base64 encoded string.

//My not-working PHP code

```
$Myfile = base64_decode($B64codedString);       
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($Myfile));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
print_r($Myfile);
```

I need to have this file saved into my PC.

Comment: base64_decode will return false on failure, and if you output that, you’ll get an “empty file”. Have you verified that $B64codedString contains what you expected it to to begin with? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: `print_r` might be problematic there, that is not what you should use for normal output, it is a debug helper function. Use echo or print instead. Apart from that, the code looks o.k. - so if it does not work as intended, you need to do some basic debugging. (And by that I mean checking the actual values used inside the script, not any “I tested this via some external service” stuff.)

Comment: I get a "string" message from a Soap Request Call, the String is encded and it is OK, as it holds a "ZIP" file, and within it, an EXCEL file. In fact, I do not get an "empty file", what I really get is a windows message when openning it that says "file is invalid".  How do I download this string as a zip file?

Comment: Well, I have used "echo" with same results. The coded string is ok, because if I use the free service to decode and download, I get the right zipped file holding a perfectly readable excel file. I do not know if it is allowed to post here the 64 coded string, for the rest of you to test it in the https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

Comment: If you just do `file_put_contents('somename.zip', $Myfile);` in your script, and download the resulting file from the server via your FTP client - do you get a working zip file then?

Comment: No, I had tried already file_put_contents("php://output", $Myfile); but I get the same result: The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'file.zip' is invalid

Comment: I meant actually write it to a file on the server, not the output buffer, not as an automatic download. If that does not work either, then your data must not be the actual ZIP data you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

//This does not work either

$Myfile = base64_decode($B64codedString);

```
$temp = tmpfile();
file_put_contents($temp, $Myfile);
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
readfile($temp);
```

I am pretty sure the B64codedString is a Zipped file with an excel file inside.